# Ubuntu 12.04 delete user and all associated directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-accounts

I have already deleted a user on Ubuntu 12.04 Server (userdel userName) however their /home/userName directory still remains. Can I simply rm -rf the users home directory or are there dependencies on this directory?

Comment: If you already removed the user you can delete the directory without worry.  Any dependencies that did exist are not relevant since the user is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the home folder. There should be no issues. You can also ask to `userdel` to do it for you next time by using the `--remove` option.